# Proper way to uninstall Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, uninstall, hyper-v

I have installed Ubuntu Server on Windows 8.1 Hyper-V virtual machine. As part of learning I just want to remove the Ubuntu Server completely so that I can reinstall the server once again to get a better understanding of the installation process.

If I delete the Virtual Machine (By remove option in Hyper - V) I am able to delete the server and the Hard Disc where the server is installed.

But using this process my Host OS Windows 8.1 is getting corrupted and I had to reinstall the Windows OS (Tried this 3 times already). Can someone please tell me the right way of uninstalling the Ubuntu Server from the Hyper-V virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you want a new operating system you just put in the install cd (or in your case you can add a iso file). After that you click the hdd you want to install it on and then you format the partition (all the files will be deleted). You've then a new os installed and the old one removed. If this is not what you want you can also use a iso to erase the hdd or you can use gparted on the ubuntu install cd to format the hdd.

Comment: Thanks .. thats helpful, I will try this approach and will let you know if I face any issues.

Comment: Thank you .. I am able to format the disc and reinstall the server properly as suggested .. Thanks